# CSS for browser's find-in-page

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Is there anyway to apply CSS rules to elements that are identified by the browser's find-in-page functionality? E.g., I could imagine a pseudo-class like `:search-result` which would apply to any elements containing text that matches the user's query. I can imagine it, but does any such thing exist, or is there a way to apply similar rules using JS?

My use case is a page with a table on it; if a user use's their browser's find function to search through the table, the browser will highlight the matching text, but I want to be able to highlight the entire row if any of it's cells contain a match.

Comment: I think such thing [if it exists] will be for sure browser dependent since each browser is free to implement his search function and there is no specification for this.

Comment: check this one : http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm it may help you

Comment: There is no API to hook into the browser's built-in find, but you could implement your own search bound to the `ctrl/cmd + f` shortcut.

Comment: I very highly doubt you can do this piggibacking on the browser functionality. You are better off writing your own custom search function to do it. Besides, do you think that users will a) be using the browser search in page functionality? [Many don't even know it exists](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/117505/how-many-users-use-browsers-text-search-within-a-page). b) the ones that do may be surprised when the tool doesn't work as they expect.

Comment: @shamsup Atlassian's Confluence application hijacks ctrl/cmd+f for their own custom find in page and I hate it. I fully support this being a browser-provided function, for exactly the reason vlaz mentioned: if your page's custom find doesn't work exactly the way my browser's find function does, I'm going to be really aggravated. That said, I don't see any reason the W3C couldn't define some CSS pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements for this, which browser's could honor regardless of how their find function actually works. But alas...

Comment: @brianmearns I didn't say it was a good practice, but if you want to hook into that functionality currently, you'll have to write your own. Another solution could be to include a search box at the top of the table, and only filter the table, leaving the browser search untouched.

Comment: @shamsup Sorry, I wasn't trying to challenge you, I understand you were offering what may be the only solution =). I was just explaining why it doesn't work for me.